# Python: create a file object from a string

Tags: python

**TLDR:** How to create in Python a file object (preferably a `io.TextIOWrapper`, but anything with a `readline()` and a `close()` method would probably do) from a string ?  I would like something like

```
f = textiowrapper_from_string("Hello\n")
s = f.readline()
f.close()
print(s)
```

to return "Hello".

**Motivation:** I have to modify an existing Python program as follows: the program stores a list (used as a stack) of file objects (more precisely, `io.TextIOWrapper`'s) that it can "pop" from and then read line-by-line:

```
f = files[-1]
line = f.readline()
...
files.pop().close()
```

The change I need to do is that sometimes, I need to push into the stack a string, and I want to be able to keep the other parts of the program unchanged, that is, I would like to add a line like:

```
files.append(textiowrapper_from_string("Hello\n"))
```

Or maybe there is another method, allowing minimal changes on the existing program ?

Comment: What was wrong with using an `io.TextIOWrapper`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: >>> import io
>>> f = io.TextIOWrapper("Hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readable'

Comment: @mkrieger1: yes, thanks! This is also fsimonjetz's answer, which I accepted. It's strange that that question doet not appear on the "Related" list on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```py
from io import StringIO

files.append(StringIO("Hello\n"))
```